# All videos with the same class autoplay on hover instead of only one with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, web, video

So I have three videos on the page and I want to autoplay only one when I hover it, and everything works except for the fact that when I hover one video all videos on the page start to play

Here is my HTML:

```
        <div class="product_bl d-flex align-items-stretch flex-column">
          <video class='videohover' width="360" height="auto" loop muted>
            <source src="assets/img/pages/landingpage.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>

        <div class="product_bl d-flex align-items-stretch flex-column">
          <video class='videohover' width="360" height="auto" loop muted>
            <source src="assets/img/pages/multilandingpage.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>

        <div class="product_bl d-flex align-items-stretch flex-column">
          <video class='videohover' width="360" height="auto"  loop muted>
            <source src="assets/img/pages/blogpage.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
```

And jQuery:

```
  var $vids = $('.videohover');

  for(let i=0; i<$vids.length; i++){
    $vids.on('mouseenter', function(){
      $vids.get(i).play();
    });
    $vids.on('mouseout', function(){
        $vids.get(i).pause();
    });
  }
```

I think I'm missing something obvious

Comment: Because you are telling jQuery to autoplay *anything* with the `.videohover` class. All the elements have this class, so they are all going to autoplay. Edit: You might be able to use [jQuery.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: do I have to make different classes for all videos?

Comment: No, you can use the function mentioned in my Edit (might need to refresh your page to see it). If you wanted to make them all unique in a sense, I might recommend using [ID's instead of classes](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Comment: can't see anything yet, will wait, thank you!

Comment: Here is the link: [jQuery.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). This let's you iterate over every element with the selector, so you could potentially add your hover code within the each function.

Answer (score 0):

here are some example for your problem..
All videos with the same class autoplay on hover instead of only one with jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".product_bl").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).children("video").get(0).play();
    }, function() {
       $(this).children("video").get(0).pause();
       
    });
});
```

```css
.product_bl {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    height: auto;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
video.videohover {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product_bl d-flex align-items-stretch flex-column">
  <video class='videohover' width="360" height="auto" loop muted>
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<div class="product_bl d-flex align-items-stretch flex-column">
  <video class='videohover' width="360" height="auto" loop muted>
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<div class="product_bl d-flex align-items-stretch flex-column">
  <video class='videohover' width="360" height="auto"  loop muted>
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

one more example jQuery for restart your video on hover again

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".product_bl").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).children("video").get(0).play();
    }, function() {
       $(this).children("video").get(0).pause();

       // Use if you want your video restart on hover again
       $(this).children("video").get(0).currentTime = 0;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply do this onReady.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.videohover').on('mouseenter', function(e){
      e.target.play();
    });
    $('.videohover').on('mouseout', function(){
        e.target.pause();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better implementation would be like this, and without using for loop:

```js
var $vids = $('.videohover')
  .on('mouseenter', function(e){
    this.play();
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(e){
     this.pause();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_bl d-flex align-items-stretch flex-column">
  <video class='videohover' width="360" height="auto" loop muted>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<div class="product_bl d-flex align-items-stretch flex-column">
  <video class='videohover' width="360" height="auto" loop muted>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<div class="product_bl d-flex align-items-stretch flex-column">
  <video class='videohover' width="360" height="auto"  loop muted>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```